# Understanding Memory Mapped Files

Tags: io, operating-system, mmap, virtual-memory, dma

I have started reading about memory mapped IO and I'm having some difficulties grasping the concepts

This is what I have understood so far:

> Each process has a virtual address space. Memory mapped files are allocated a
>          specific address range in the virtual address space, that maps to the same address on 
>          the physical memory. This way, all the writes that are done by the disk controller on
>          the memory(through DMA) will be reflected to the process without any additional 
>          copying. (In a non memory mapped file case, CPU will have to copy the contents over 
>          to the buffer of the process).

My Doubts:

- Is my understanding correct?
- What will happen if there are multiple processes trying to mmap a
     file and there is no continuous block of memory available for direct mapping?

Comment: I'm removing the Java and NIO tags; this doesn't seem to be Java-specific at all.

Answer (score 8):

The memory subsystem itself doesn't have any understanding of "files", which are an OS concept, and there have been [some operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeyKOS) that didn't use files at all. You're close but a little off in your understanding of how `mmap` works.

Each process does have its own virtual address space, which may have very little to do with the physical memory (lots of virtual address space doesn't have any memory associated at all, ever, and virtual memory that's swapped out doesn't have any physical memory). The system uses some sort of lookup tables (called [descriptor tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) on x86) that specify what virtual address ranges map to what physical address ranges. Virtual memory that isn't "resident" (swapped out, `mmap`ped but not loaded) has a "not present" entry.

Whenever a program tries to access this memory, the CPU causes a page fault, which tells the OS to go find the appropriate contents somewhere and load them into physical memory. In the case of swap, the contents are loaded out of a swap file or partition; in the case of `mmap`, they're loaded out of somewhere in the filesystem.

The mechanism for getting them into physical memory and updating the descriptor table can vary. What you're describing is DMA, which lets the drive controller copy contents directly into a block of physical memory, and zero-copy I/O, which is a technique where the OS just creates a new descriptor mapping telling the processor to "teleport" the region of physical memory into the program's address space. Neither is technically required for `mmap` (the OS could load the file "by hand" and copy it into a new buffer for the program, and this may happen in a read-copy-update situation), but modern systems do it like you described.

The physical memory doesn't necessarily have to be contiguous. When the POSIX version of `mmap` is called, the OS allocates `length` bytes for the mapping, but thanks to virtual memory, those bytes could be split up among multiple blocks and mapped together by the processor.

If multiple processes are trying to `mmap` the same file, the OS behavior depends on whether the access is read-only or read/write; read-only copies can be shared among many processes (such as the actual executable code; this is why even though Chrome may have dozens of processes running, the Chrome binary is only in memory once).